# How can I use a controller of one module in another module?

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller

I have this folder structure:

```
module1/
    init.js
    controller/
        module1controller.js
    view/
    ...
module2/
    init.js
    controller/
        module2controller.js
    view/  
        module2view.js
```

The file `module1/init.js` now looks like this

```
Ext.application({
    name:'module1',
    appFolder:'/projects/modules/module1/',
    requires:[
        'Ext.container.Viewport',
        'Ext.layout.container.Border'
    ],
    controllers:['module1controller'], // Here I want to load controller from module2
    autoCreateViewport:true
});
```

I wonder how can I use in this `module1` views and controllers from `module2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Ext.application({
        paths: {
            'm2': "../module2" 
        },
        name:'module1',
        appFolder:'/projects/modules/module1/',
        requires:[
            'Ext.container.Viewport',
            'Ext.layout.container.Border'
        ],
        controllers:['module1controller', 'm2.module2controller'], 
        autoCreateViewport:true
    });
```

Comment: Thanks!! I will check it in a moment

Comment: Hm. There is some trouble. If `m2` is simply `"../module2"`, then browser can not find module2controller. If however I change it to "../module2/controller", then it tries to seek `module2view.js` in `"../module2/controller/view/"` which is not right. I hope, you know how to fix this.

Comment: It seems as I found a correct way of doing this thing. m2 should remain "../module2", but inside controllers brakets it should be: `controllers:['module1controller','m2.controller.module2controller']`. In this case all scripts are loaded.

Comment: for all the required views and stores you need to add them in requires.
requires : ['m2.view.module2view'] here m2 is the path to module2.

Comment: Yes, I know that (but I think I used relative paths in the controller, which was the main reason of the first crash, I guess). That works good now. Thank you, sir! PS. Never knew that Sencha's MVC pattern is so neat.